# Non-genetic local search algorithm

Tags: java, nodes, dynamic-programming, computer-science

This assignment is based on the definition of the Traveling Salesperson Problem. I want to find the shortest route that visits every city and ends up back at the original starting city. The goal is to use a non-genetic local search algorithm or algorithms to find the shortest paths.

For example:
The option would be two swap the order of two cities and see if this shortens the tour:

- Mpls. => Seattle => Detroit => Boston => Chicago => Miami => Denver => Mpls.

I am having difficulties in coding based on this algorithm. So, I was wondering if someone can show me how I can do it on my program.

[Sample Output for the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irPZf.png)

> Two types of output: Summary Mode and Verbose Mode. Verbose Mode should print to a file every path you try until your program terminates. Summary mode, which prints to the console, should print a path only when that path is better than any path that you have found previously. In all cases, print the single-letter mnemonic of the city (Node).

[Additional Requirements for the code that I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUZQ8.png)

Here the code I work on for the past hours.

Graph Class:

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     //Graph is a class whose objects represent graphs.
public class Graph {
   ArrayList<Node> nodeList;
   ArrayList<Edge> edgeList;
  
   public Graph() {
       nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
       edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();
  
   }
  
   public ArrayList<Node> getNodeList() {
       return nodeList;
   }
   public ArrayList<Edge> getEdgeList() {
       return edgeList;
   }
   public void addNode(Node n) {
       nodeList.add(n);
   }
   public void addEdge(Edge e) {
       edgeList.add(e);
   }
   public String toString() {
       String s = "Graph g.\n";
       if (nodeList.size() > 0) {
           for (Node n : nodeList) {
       // Print node info
       String t = "\nNode " + n.getName() + ", abbrev " + n.getAbbrev() + ", value " + n.getVal() + "\n";
       s = s.concat(t);
       }
       s = s.concat("\n");
           }
       return s;
   }
}
```

Node Class:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
// Node is a class whose objects represent nodes (a.k.a., vertices) in the graph.
public class Node {
   String name;
   String val; // The value of the Node
   String abbrev; // The abbreviation for the Node
   ArrayList<Edge> outgoingEdges;
   ArrayList<Edge> incomingEdges;
  
  
   String color; //Create the color of the TYPE Node List
   int start; //Create the Starting Time
   int end; //Create the Ending Time
  
  
   public Node( String theAbbrev ) {
       setAbbrev( theAbbrev );
       val = null;
       name = null;
       outgoingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
       incomingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
   }
  
   public String getAbbrev() {
       return abbrev;
   }
  
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
  
   public String getVal() {
       return val;
   }
  
   public ArrayList<Edge> getOutgoingEdges() {
       return outgoingEdges;
   }
  
   public ArrayList<Edge> getIncomingEdges() {
       return incomingEdges;
   }
  
   public void setAbbrev( String theAbbrev ) {
       abbrev = theAbbrev;
   }
  
   public void setName( String theName ) {
       name = theName;
   }
  
   public void setVal( String theVal ) {
       val = theVal;
   }
  
   public void addOutgoingEdge( Edge e ) {
       outgoingEdges.add( e );
   }
  
   public void addIncomingEdge( Edge e ) {
       incomingEdges.add( e );
   }
  
  
   //Create the Starting Time of the Node
   public int getStartTime() {
       return start;
   }
   //Create the Finshing Time of the Node
   public int getFinishTime() {
       return end;
   }
   public void setColor(String string) {
       color = string;
   }
   public String getColor() {
       return color;
   }
   //Set Starting-Time
   public void setStartTime(int time) {
       start = time;
      
   }
   //Set Finishing-Time
   public void setFinishTime(int time) {
       end = time;
}
```

Edge Class:

```
 //import java.util.*;
// Edge between two nodes
// Edge is a class whose objects represent edges (a.k.a., arcs) between nodes of the graph.
public class Edge {
  
   String label;
   int dest;
   int dist;
   Node tail;
   Node head;
  
   //String Type(Forward,Backward,Cross,Tree)
   String name;
  
   public Edge( Node tailNode, Node headNode, String theLabel ) {
       setLabel( theLabel );
       setTail( tailNode );
       setHead( headNode );
   }
  
   public Edge(int dest, int dist,String label,String name)
   {
       //Create the destination Vertex Index
       this.dest = dest;
       this.dist = dist; // Source Vertex index
       this.label=label; // Label of Edge
       this.name= name; // (Locate the Type of Line(F,B,C,T)
       }
  
   public String getLabel() {
       return label;
   }
  
   public Node getTail() {
       return tail;
   }
  
   public Node getHead() {
       return head;
   }
  
   public int getDist() {
       return dist;
   }
  
   public void setLabel( String s ) {
       label = s;
   }
  
   public void setTail( Node n ) {
       tail = n;
   }
  
   public void setHead( Node n ) {
       head = n;
   }
  
   public void setDist( String s ) {
       try {
           dist = Integer.parseInt( s );
       }
       catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
           dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       }
   }
   public String getType() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setType(String string) {
       this.name = string;
   }
}
```

Main Driver:

```
  import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class DelivC {
   File inputFile;
   File outputFile;
   PrintWriter output;
   Graph g;
  
   public DelivC( File in, Graph gr ) {
       inputFile = in;
       g = gr;
      
       // Get output file name.
       String inputFileName = inputFile.toString();
       String baseFileName = inputFileName.substring( 0, inputFileName.length()-4 ); // Strip off ".txt"
       String outputFileName = baseFileName.concat( "_out.txt" );
       outputFile = new File( outputFileName );
       if ( outputFile.exists() ) { // For retests
           outputFile.delete();
       }
      
       try {
           output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);          
       }
       catch (Exception x ) {
           System.err.format("Exception: %s%n", x);
           System.exit(0);
       }
       System.out.println( "DelivC: To be implemented");
       output.println( "DelivC: To be implemented");
       output.flush();
   }
}
```

Comment: in which method are trying to implement this algorithm? And what is your MainDriver for. Does it have anything to do with that

Comment: I need to implement at the main driver since I need to do a shortest paths for the txt file. The main driver is a part of a GUI where it can open a file and then when selecting to DelivC class the output file should display the result of which route is the shortest.

Comment: also I would remove the ArrayList<Edge> incomingEdges; list in Node class and the Node head; reference in Edge class, since always setting them correctly could be quite complicated. Instead you should just have two edges if two nodes are connected in both directions. And the edges themselfs don't need a reference to their origin node. This makes working with the code way easier. Also there is no benefit in knowing the incomingNodes inside of a Node object.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant.

Comment: @IntoVoid No, I cannot remove them because it part of the program and if I remove them the program won't work properly. It will give me some errors to it.